# Two Fragments should never communicate directly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have **Activity A and B**. **A has fragment AF, B has BF.**

From AF I am navigating to fragment BF like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, B.REQUEST_CODE);
```

From B activity I am loading BF fragment like this:

```
BF bf = new BF();
bf.init(this);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.bfFragmentHolder,bf)
      .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

After finishing the work in BF fragment I am passing some data to B activity via an interface with some data object and going back to A activity's AF fragment like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

After that AF fragment's `onStart()` is getting called.

My question is how can i pass data to BF to AF fragment? I know its suggested not to commiunicate directly. But how can i send data there? Should I use the Intent to pass Data to A activity then pass it to AF fragment?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to make use of event bus it even supports different thread modes which you can utilise https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: i want to but adding an additional library will increase dex count. we are already in the limit. should i try viewmodel store?

Comment: No it will not event bus is really lightweight even less than 3kb just go through it's documentation!!

Comment: Eventbus has nothing to do with dex count however if you are facing dexing issues eliminating other libraries with more than 65k method count might help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, one way to think of this, is to make use of something that manages the state across your entire app, since you are forced to have multiple activities, but yet you need to have some way of communication between them, AppManager would be an ideal way to tackle such a problem.

You would inject/initiate AppManager with your app launch, and have it tied to your Application class, I guess having it as a Singleton would be ideal as well.

However, I feel the urge to mention this as well, but if you can combine Activity A and Activity B into a single Container Activity, and have the fragments AF and BF transitioning using the Navigation Component, then have a shared view model across the container activity, fragments AF and BF, that would be a much nicer way, but I know that you might be limited or tight to a legacy code.

One last thing, and that might be a personal opinion, but having EventBus handling such data transitions, would be against all the architecture rules or laws were set in your application, you literally force override any top-down approach to handle the data with as easy as posting an event that is being listened anywhere in application, not like ViewModels which do have a scope always that are being tied to.

Hope this fixes your issue !

Comment: We can use ViewModelStore.

Comment: @JasonBourne One way would be that, but I feel a lot of boilerplate code coming from behind this line:


`If an owner of this ViewModelStore is destroyed and is not going to be recreated, then it should call clear() on this ViewModelStore, so ViewModels would be notified that they are no longer used.`